# Any Magento One Step Checkout Extension that support Network Online?

Tags: magento, module, payment-gateway, payment

Want to know is there is any one page checkout extension for magento that support network online payment method too.

Please Reply if any ?

Regards
M.Zain Gulzar

Comment: Can you give us a link or explain what the _Network Online_ payment method is exactly? I've never heard of such a payment service provider.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Asking for extensions is explicitly off-topic. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?