# issue using one page checkout magento and network online payment method

Tags: magento

I was using one page checkout for magento but when i do select network online payment method in checkout it do stuck and show me loading image only.

Now i am using free magento extensions one page checkout it shows many errors attaching erros screenshot

please do help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any Magento One Step Checkout Extension that support Network Online?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155423/any-magento-one-step-checkout-extension-that-support-network-online)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot is only showing one error. It looks, judging by the underscore in front of the method name, '_idpt', that you are trying to statically call either a private or protected function. I would go to that class file and see how it is declared.

Comment: @ZainGee Did this answer work for you? If so, please mark it as accepted so that I can get credit for it. Better late than never. Thanks!